# `Web3.utils` is undefined and `Web3.eth` is undefined

Tags: javascript, web3js

After upgreading Web3 from `1.0.0-beta.34` to `1.0.0-beta.37` a try to access any properties of `Web3.utils`, `Web3.eth`, `Web3.bzz` and `Web3.shh` will give an error. For example, calling `web3.utils.utf8ToHex('some string')` at `2_deploy_contract.js` as follow:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
web3.utils.utf8ToHex('some string');
```

Is raising the following exception:

```
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'utf8ToHex' of undefined
```

---

And I found that the following code snippet:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
console.log("Web3.eth = " + Web3.eth)
console.log("Web3.utils = " + Web3.utils)
console.log("Web3.bzz = " + Web3.bzz)
console.log("Web3.shh = " + Web3.shh)
```

Will output:

```
> Web3.eth = undefined 
> Web3.utils = undefined 
> Web3.bzz = undefined
> Web3.shh = undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static properties (`Web3.utils`, `Web3.eth` and etc...) got removed because if someone is just using the `utils` then he should probably use the `web3-utils` and  `web3-eth` module directly, instead of bundling the complete library ([ref](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2419#issuecomment-467328609)).

Sample working code:

```
const Web3Utils = require('web3-utils');
const someString = Web3Utils.utf8ToHex('some string');
```

Note: The long term goal will be to remove the Web3 class and to create the Web3 Namespace. But this will be done after the stable release ([ref](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2419#issuecomment-467328609)).